# Правильно составить post запрос

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

помогите составить правильно post-запрос на js. Есть сайт, на который отправляется post запрос. Есть результат, как должны выглядеть данные. 
[image]

Но я никак не могу понять, как правильно его составить.

```
var cers = '2890';
$.ajax({
type: 'post',
url: "страница обработчик",
data: cers
processData: false,
contentType: false,
})
```

У меня выходит вот такая лажа:
[image]
Либо вот так:
[image]

И собственно данные не обрабатываются.

Спасибо за любую помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение и оно довольно глупое. 
Перед запросом не объявил вот это:

```
Var f_d = new FormData();
f_d.append("parcel141244", cers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто данные передавайте при помощи объекта

```
var cers = '2890';
$.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   url: "страница обработчик",
   data: {
       parcell:cers
   }
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
})
```

Comment: К сожалению, это не помогло. Но я все же нашёл решение.